# Is there any software to record and replay mouse movements and clicks with button Id support?

Tags: windows, mouse, record

Before I endeavor to develop my own solution to this I am wondering if anyone has stumbled on something like this because my search results have yielded nothing.

I am looking for mouse recording software that will allow me to record clicks on specific apllications but it will keep track of the button ids as well so as to repeat those clicks even if the software launches in a different resolution etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/).

Answer (score 0):

Autoit does the first half of what you want. Though since it has scripting ability, I imagine you can get the current resolution and calculate the position for a different one.

Example:

```
; Double click at the x, y position of 0, 500.
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 0, 500, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As anther poster suggested you can use AutoIt for this. However, you want to use [ControlClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm) to click a button/control so your script won't be dependent on screen resolution. You can find the ID of most controls using the [AutoIt Window Information Tool](http://AutoIt%20Window%20Information%20Tool) and then just use it with ControlClick. For example:

```
ControlClick("Window Name", "", 762)
```

You can also use TEXT, CLASS, CLASSNN, NAME, REGEXPCLASS and  X \ Y \ W \ to click a control using ControlClick.